# Issue while updating Primary and foreign key using deferred FK

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to update my primary and foreign key. After searching a lot, I came across the concept of a deferred key. I am able to update my PK and FK using SQLscript in PL/SQL. However I am getting an error while doing the same thing using PHP. Below is my code for PHP.

```
$update_p="update project set project_id='$projectname' where project_id='$previousproject'";
            $up=oci_parse($conn,$update_p);


$update_m="update members set project='$projectname' where project='$previousproject'";
$um=oci_parse($conn,$update_m);

$commit="commit";
$c=oci_parse($conn,$commit);

oci_execute($up);

oci_execute($um);

oci_execute($c);
echo"Project Updated!";
```

Comment: He who is changing the value of a Primary Key, doesn't understand the concept of integrity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you were able to do that in PL/SQL script, but it's not enough to declare a constraint as deferrable.

You should also mark a deferrable constraint as deferred in your transaction:

[image]

> Specify DEFERRED to indicate that the conditions specified by the
>   deferrable constraint are checked when the transaction is committed.

So you need to make your constraints as deferred before updating the table.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you need to explicitly [set the *session*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_2013.htm#SQLRF53047) as well as the key to allow for deferred constraints.

If we assume the following environment:

```
create table tmp_1 (
    pk number
  , fk number
  , constraint pk_tmp_1 primary key (pk)
    );

create table tmp_2 (
    pk number
  , fk number
  , constraint pk_tmp_2 primary key (pk)
  , constraint fk_tmp_2 foreign key (fk) references tmp_1 (pk)
    );

alter table tmp_1 
  add constraint fk_tmp_1 
      foreign key (fk)
      references tmp_2(pk)
      deferrable;
```

If you attempt an insert you'll get the following error:

```
SQL> insert into tmp_1 values (1, 2);
insert into tmp_1 values (1, 2)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (MF.FK_TMP_1) violated - parent key not found


SQL> insert into tmp_2 values (2, 1);
insert into tmp_2 values (2, 1)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (MF.FK_TMP_2) violated - parent key not found
```

However, by altering the session to set the constraints parameter to deferred this will work:

```
SQL> alter session set constraints = deferred;

Session altered.

SQL>
SQL> insert into tmp_1 values (1, 2);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into tmp_2 values (2, 1);

1 row created.
```

Here, deferred *"indicates that the conditions specified by the deferrable constraint are checked when the transaction is committed"* as opposed to when the DML occurs.

Though circular dependencies can sometimes be necessary Oracle doesn't go out of it's way to make life easy for you - it shouldn't. If you have circular dependencies it's always worth re-evaluating your data-model to ensure that these are required.

Comment: I created the table by writting:create table members(
Project varchar(45),
Member_email varchar(45),
Var_del number,
foreign key (Project) references project(project_id) initially deferred); I am able to update PK and FK in PLSQL. As you mentioned I need to alter session. I did that. Still no luck.